# how to deploy ember-cli project in apache server

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have the following problem.

I created an ember application with ember-cli.

The application works fine on nodejs through the url `http://localhost:4200/` when running the command `ember serve`

I want to deploy this application on an apache httpd server.

In order that this will work i think that it should work also standalone when opening in firefox.

When i open it in firefox i get an error:

> require is not defined

The generated index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Foo</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no">

    <base href="/" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/foo.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.FooENV = {"environment":"development","baseURL":"/","locationType":"auto","EmberENV":{"FEATURES":{}},"APP":{"LOG_RESOLVER":true,"LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION":true,"LOG_MODULE_RESOLVER":true,"LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS":true},"LOG_MODULE_RESOLVER":true};
      window.EmberENV = window.FooENV.EmberENV;
    </script>
    <script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/foo.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.Foo = require('foo/app')['default'].create(FooENV.APP);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can i solve this issue?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Did you first build the project with `ember build --environment production`? It will build the project and add it to the `/dist` folder and then you can use that.

Comment: Yes. i found that if i open it in chrome it complains that it doesn't find my vendor.js "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///J:/assets/ndd.css" How can i fix this?

Comment: Probably you are referencing an image or file in your css that you don't have in the assets folder. Check the guides how to add assets such as images,fonts etc and how to include them http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/asset-compilation/

Comment: it also complains on js files. If i run it through http://localhost:4200/ everything works

Comment: You need to deploy the files from `/dist` to your server. You can't run it without serving from a server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
file:///J:/assets/ndd.css
```

This looks to me like you just double clicked your index.html file in your dist folder. This does not work!

You have to serve your directory by an http-server.

Install a simple http server with npm:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

Move to your dist folder and run `http-server`. You will see a message like this:

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./ on port: 8080
```

Now you can check your ember app in Firefox on: `http://localhost:8080`

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you have to do in order to correctly deploy an Ember CLI app in apache.

Let's assume you are going to use `XAMPP`. You are probably going to create a folder inside `htdocs` and name it `myapp`. When running the `ember new appname` command from within `myapp`, the CLI when generate the whole project and put it inside `appname` folder.

Now, when you will build the project when `ember build`, the whole compiled version of the app will be located in: `myapp\appname\dist`.

Because Ember CLI uses the `base` meta tag in `index.html`, you will need to modify the **`baseUrl`** variable in `myapp\appname\config\environment.js`, and set it to `myapp/appname/dist/`. Rebuild and the app will work by visiting **`localhost/myapp/appname/dist`**

This is a slightly complicated and totally unpractical folder structure, but it is a good example of how it works and I'm sure newcomers will stumble upon the exact same use case.