# how to use ember.js without server

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am following the ember.js example on [this site (http://todomvc.com/)](http://todomvc.com/).
I clone this project to my computer and just double click `index.html` and
it runs, as what I expect.

But in [ember's guide](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/ember-cli/), it tells me to install the ember-cli, and create a new project, then build it.

```
ember new myapp
ember build
```

I can find my files in `/dist`, but when I double click the `index.html`
it fails.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782035/how-to-deploy-ember-cli-project-in-apache-server) said, "You have to serve your directory with an http server."

Why do I need a server to run this project, instead of just opening it in my browser?

Comment: run: ember server :) the browser should open automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example that you linked is using the old global Ember. This is very different from ember-cli which you are now working with. An http server is required because of the `<base>` tag in the `index.html` file that specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document. So when your app is trying to serve up the `assets/app.js` or `assets/vendor.js`, its trying to look relative to this base url, which is defined in `config/environment.js`. It defaults to `/`. So you need a server to respond to the resource requests for the assets. Notice that your `assets` folder is relative to the `index.html` file

Comment: thanks for your answer. where can I found the detail of different between old Ember and the new one(with ember-cli)? I have googled it but found notinhg.

Comment: The http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/controllers/ docs are for the older global style